# push notification receiving more than one time in worklight 6.0 after Updating the applicaion

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, google-cloud-messaging, worklight-server

I have implemented push notification in worklight 6.0 via GCM, but I am receiving the push notification more than 1 time.
          When I am updating my application by direct update, I am getting extra one push notification, For Example: 3 extra push notification for 3 update after installation. But when I install the application for the first time it works fine.

Comment: You will need to expend on the way you have implemented it. Are you using the sample project as-is, or have you created your own? If your own, what is the flow of your application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug in Worklight 6.0.
It was fixed in the latest fixpack (6.0.0.2).
See http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24036987 for download
and http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27039801 for more details.