# Issue in push Notification in worklight

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to implement push notification in worklight targeted for android devices. I have a problem . When first i run the push notification , then it is working fine. But after updating the code using direct update, then the push notification call back function is called  the number of the times the app is updated. What should i do.

The below is the javascript code i used to receive the push notification

```
if (WL.Client.Push) {
    WL.Client.Push.onReadyToSubscribe = function () {
        WL.Client.Push.registerEventSourceCallback(
            "myPushh",
            "BackEnd",
            "PushEventSource",
            pushNotificationReceived);
    };
}

function pushNotificationReceived(props, payload) {
    alert('Push Notification Received');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found similar question and there was a answer for that to . So i am going to give link for the question and answer .

[push notification receiving more than one time in worklight 6.0 after Updating the applicaion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21699840/push-notification-receiving-more-than-one-time-in-worklight-6-0-after-updating-t)